# Howcome assembly does not have an signed and unsigned subraction instruction?

Tags: assembly, signed, unsigned-integer

I am making a virtual machine and a C compiler for it. Something I do not get though is how most instruction sets have a IMUL and IDIV but not a ISUB and an IADD. Since sub is usually unsigned sub how could I do something like in x86

```
MOV EAX,1
MOV EDX,3
SUB EAX,EDX,EAX
```

and get -2?

Comment: Are you familiar with two's complement?

Comment: FWIW [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Integer) does have both unsigned and signed addition and subtraction (differing on whether they check for overflow or not).

Comment: Even more interesting, with 2's complement, the low half of the result of multiplication is independent of signedness as well. That's why there are no versions of `mul` that only give the low part, `imul` already does that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signed addition always produces the same bit patterns as output as unsigned addition -- only the interpretation of them is different -- so there is no need to have separate instructions for the two cases. It's the same for subtraction.

The general ADD and SUB instructions set two groups of condition flags such that you can later check for the outcome of a SUB-based comparison using ja/jb for unsigned comparisions or jg/jl for signed ones.

(More precisely: If you already have instructions that do unsigned addition/subtraction modulo 2^wordlen, then the bit patterns they produce will be correct for every 2's complement *signed* addition/subtraction whose true result is representable. Mathematically this is because unsigned integers and 2's complement signed integers are just different choices of canonical representatives of residue classes modulo 2^wordlength).

Comment: When the signed format uses a twos-complement representation, that is.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Sure, but when did you last see an architecture that used a different representation than 2's-complement for signed integer arithmetic?

Answer (score 5):

There is only one instruction of each, as subtraction and addition yields the same result regardless of the arguments being signed or unsigned.